# Performancetest: Flash/AS3 Processing/Java and openFrameworks/C++

Tags: java, c++, actionscript-3, performance, testing

I need to compare the performance of AS3, Processing and openFrameworks for my Bachelor thesis. Are there any comparison tables you know of or do I have to do the test myself?

How would a good test look like? I'm just focused on graphics so I thought about maybe three different programs, a 2d-graphics app, a typographic-app and a 3d-app. Are there any pitfalls? What's the best way to test the performance?

All suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Apparently university libraries have books on just this sort of thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know in the AS3 world there is a popular performance monitor called stats, you can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/mrdoob/wiki/stats). Honestly I think you may be comparing apples to oranges. My initial assumption would be that openFrameworks (C++) outperforms Processing (Java) and Processing outperforms AS3 for many of the problems you will be exploring. I am sure there are many Java performance monitors and C++ monitors that you can plug into your Processing and openFramework programs to collect the data you need or you can roll your own.

Of course you also need to identify what exactly you will be testing. My initial thought would be to test framerates, memory consumption, CPU utilization, and execution time. Personally I like to develop particle emitters and push my programs to the limit on the number of particles it can process. You will quickly see that Processing and openFramworks kicks AS3's butt with this.

Well I hope I helped.

Have fun!

Nick @
nickgs.com